# Does the web page developed in 4.0 framework will work in 2.0 framework?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, web-config

I have asked to develop a web page for a website which is actually in asp.net 2.0.

I got code and opened in Visual web developer express edition 2010 it prompted me to convert that web site from 2.0 to 4.0 i clicked ok.

I build the webpage and it is successfully running.

Does the web page i have build in Visual Web developer edition will work in asp.net 2.0??

It it is not. then what changes does i need to do for this to work.?

Moreover the web page which i have build is only basic framework part.

Answer (score 0):

A web application compiled for .NET 4 will not run on a pure .NET 2 environment.

Set the TargetFramework back to .NET 2 in the web app Properties, Compile, Advanced Compiler Settings.

I don't want to nag, but isn't there a way to host the site in a .NET 4 or maybe even .NET 4.5 environment? Personally I would prefer that, because then you can use the latest .NET gimmicks.